# My CSS transition for a button on hover is pushing the container down

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a transition on an HTML `h3` tag that I have made into a button. On `:hover` I have made it translate down the y axis 10px and scale up by 1.10. When the transition takes place it pushes the container down ever so slightly as I'll show in screen shots:

[image]

[image]

I know it's hard to see but it pushes down about 2-5 pixels. I haven't been able to figure out why this happens. I have recreated this issue here: http://codepen.io/marlee/pen/VaLZPW?editors=1100

Here is the html:

```
<article class="about-page-cta">
      <h3>Want to get to know us better?</h3>
        <a href="contact.html"><h4 class="contact-us-button">CONTACT US</h4>     </a>
    </article>
```

And CSS:

```
.about-page-cta{
 background-color: #30c0d8;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 2rem 0 2rem 0
 }

.about-page-cta h3{
margin-top: 0;
padding-top: 2rem;
color: white;
}

.about-page-cta a {
text-decoration: none;
}

.contact-us-button{
color: white;
background: #FF6952;
border-radius: 10%;
border: none;
padding: .75rem;
margin: 1rem;
transition: transform, background, .5s ease;
transform: scale(1);
}

.contact-us-button:hover{
background: #ff5339;
box-shadow: 0 0 6px white;
transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: We can't help you since `however, the codepen recreation doesn't have the same push-down effect.` Which browser are you testing this on? Are there  elements that you excluded in the codepen...can they be causing the issue?

Comment: I posted the codepen in case someone caught something while looking at it that I might have missed. I am using chrome. I can try to add more of the pages elements into the codepen and see if something changes.  @stackErr

Comment: Okay, since I added a lot of the other elements from the page to the code I have been able to recreate the push down effect here: http://codepen.io/marlee/pen/VaLZPW?editors=1100
@stackErr

Comment: Have you tried CSS `overflow: hidden;`? Found here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: So in that case what would I put `overflow: hidden` on? I tried putting it on the call to action container ie. `.about-page-cta` and it didn't seem to change anything. @jeff

Comment: See you got your problem solved below, but how about putting `overflow: hidden` on the HTML `<body>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `border-bottom` on `hover` of `anchor tag`..

```
a:hover{
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #FF6952;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #30C0D8;
}
```

Remove the border-bottom property or be more specific where you want to apply the border. Or

```
.about-page-cta a:hover {
border:0;
}
```

I guess that should solve the problem...

*line 86 of your codepen

Comment: Thanks so much! You're right. I changed the specificity. Cheers. @moid

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)